# Accessing internal member from outside

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface, accessibility

In SolutionA (Namespace name), I am calling a a memeber (functionA()) of internal class (ClassA )from another class (Engine)and this class through interface (IClassA).

IClassA declares this function 
Engine Calls this function and using another method (smame method name in this case).

So if i want to call this internal member in another solution.

So in Solution B

I can do this :

```
using SolutionA;


IClassA iA;

iA = new Engine();

iA.fuctionA();
```

I guess it should give functionA when i do a [.] after iA , but intellisense is not giving ..whats wrong here?

Why i am not getting the functionA in SolutionB?

More info about my architechure:

```
//IClassA.cs
namespace namespaceA
{
internal class ClassA
{
    public string FunctionA(){}
}
}

//Engine.cs

namespace namespaceA
{
public class Engine() : IClassA()
{
    public IClassA.FunctionA(){}
}
}

// IClassA.cs
namespace namespaceA
{
public interface IClassA()
{
    string FunctionA(string data);
}
}

//ClassB.cs

namespace namespaceB
{
using  namespaceA;

internal class Classb
{
    IClassA engine = new namespaceA.Engine();

    engine.FunctionA();  //here i am unable to get fuuction
}
}
```

Comment: If you have two solutions, do you need to use [InternalsVisibleTo]?(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Does the `IClassA` interface declare the function? My guess is that it doesn't. Given that the compile-time class of `iA` is `IClassA`, the compiler (and Intellisense) will only let you use members of `IClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that this is your problem, but I'll mention it because it is another problem that could cause your symptoms.  If `functionA` has the [`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute, it will not show up in Intellisense when you are in a different assembly.  Though in that situation, ignoring Intellisense and using `functionA` would still allow the program to compile.